# Redis StackExchange SortedSetAdd not updating existing element

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have just started to learn Redis and as I'm programming in C# I'm using StackExchange Redis. I wanted to try out SortedSet, and here is simple code that I have:

Create sample data

```
  private List<User> SeedUsers() {
        var list = new List<User> {
            new User {Id = 1.ToString(), UserName = "Test1", Score = 10},
            new User {Id = 2.ToString(), UserName = "Test2", Score = 23},
            new User {Id = 3.ToString(), UserName = "Test3", Score = 15},
            new User {Id = 4.ToString(), UserName = "Test4", Score = 250},
            new User {Id = 5.ToString(), UserName = "Test5", Score = 100},
            new User {Id = 6.ToString(), UserName = "Test5", Score = 23},
            ......
        };
        return list;
    }
```

Add data to Redis

```
 public bool AddUsersToLeaderBoard() {
        var db = Connection.GetDatabase();
        var list = SeedUsers();
        var numOfSuccesses = 0;

        foreach (var item in list) {
            var r = db.SortedSetAdd("test", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item), item.Score);
            if (r) numOfSuccesses++;
        }

        var i = list[3];
        i.Score = 888;
        db.SortedSetAdd("test", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(i), i.Score);
        return numOfSuccesses == list.Count;
    }
```

What's confusing to me is part after foreach loop, where I change 4th element of list, and then I add it to sorted set, but it is just added twice, i.e. it is not updated in Redis.

Have I misunderstood this part of Redis documentation ?

> Just a final note about sorted sets before switching to the next topic. Sorted sets' scores can be updated at any time. Just calling ZADD against an element already included in the sorted set will update its score (and position) with O(log(N)) time complexity. As such, sorted sets are suitable when there are tons of updates.

Also to make sure that there is not any problem with JSON serialization I tried this line of code:

```
 var x = db.SortedSetRank("test", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list[4]), Order.Descending);
```

Which gave expected results. So what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not the same object, you updated it's score before pushing it to Redis.
Do it like this instead:

```
public bool AddUsersToLeaderBoard() {
    var db = Connection.GetDatabase();
    var list = SeedUsers();
    var numOfSuccesses = 0;

    foreach (var item in list) {
        var r = db.SortedSetAdd("test", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item), item.Score);
        if (r) numOfSuccesses++;
    }

    var i = list[3];
    //i.Score = 888; - this line can be removed
    db.SortedSetAdd("test", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(i), 888);
    return numOfSuccesses == list.Count;
}
```

And the output of zrange will be the expected one (with Test4 only once and the real score of 888):

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange test 0 -1 withscores
1) "{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Score\":10,\"UserName\":\"Test1\"}"
2) "10"
3) "{\"Id\":\"3\",\"Score\":15,\"UserName\":\"Test3\"}"
4) "15"
5) "{\"Id\":\"2\",\"Score\":23,\"UserName\":\"Test2\"}"
6) "23"
7) "{\"Id\":\"6\",\"Score\":23,\"UserName\":\"Test5\"}"
8) "23"
9) "{\"Id\":\"5\",\"Score\":100,\"UserName\":\"Test5\"}"
10) "100"
11) "{\"Id\":\"4\",\"Score\":250,\"UserName\":\"Test4\"}"
12) "888"
```